# How to add columns to a tkinter.Listbox?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to add these panda columns to a `Listbox`, so they read like this:

```
New Zealand NZD
United States USD
```

ETC.

I am using pandas to get the data from a .csv, but when I try and use a for loop to add the items to the list box using insert I get the error

`NameError: name 'END' is not defined` or
`NameError: name 'end' is not defined`

Using this code:

```
def printCSV():
    csv_file = ('testCUR.csv')

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

    print (df[['COUNTRY','CODE']])

your_list = (df[['COUNTRY','CODE']])
for item in your_list:

       listbox.insert(end, item)
```

Comment: Use the string `"end"`. Also, a listbox can only have a single column.

Comment: what I want is for them to display as above and then only use the country code as the value so ipresume I would have to create a for loop or something which creates the string to put into the listbox but how to get only the country code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the csv file into a dictionary, use the combined country and currency codes as the keys and just the codes as the values, and finally insert the keys into the `Listbox`. To get the code of the current selection, you can do this: `currencies[listbox.selection_get()]`.

`listbox.selection_get()` returns the key which you then use to get the currency code in the `currencies` dict.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

currencies = {}

with open('testCUR.csv') as f:
    next(f, None)  # Skip the header.
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for country, code in reader:
        currencies[f'{country} {code}'] = code

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
for key in currencies:
    listbox.insert('end', key)
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
listbox.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda event: print(currencies[listbox.selection_get()]))

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Press the enter key to print the currency code of the current selection. The f-string (`f'{country} {code}'`) only works in Python 3.6+, in other version you can use the `.format` method.